# window.open() makes my app crash on blackberry10

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry-10

I am struggeling with my `blackberry10` application. Basically I want to open the `BlackBerry World` page of my application by pressing on a button in a confirmation dialog.

```
function onButtonPressed() {
    var url = "appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/XXXXXXXX"
    window.open( url, "_blank" );
}
```

But after pressing my button the app craches immediately without any error in the debug console. I also tried to use `"_system"` instead of `"_blank"` without success. However on `android` my approach works flawlessly.

Are there any further hints or tips to investigate/solve this problem?

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/issues/41

Comment: Check pop blocking: "Note! window.open() does not work without an actual user click
due to popup blocking."

Comment: I have already checked the settings according to [blackberry 10 config.xml configuration](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/blackberry10/config.html)

Comment: did you try adding semicolumn at the end of your string? I had once issues with android, maybe blackberry is same

Comment: This is just a typo in my question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using another `cordova` plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bb-invoke
```

Now I am able to open the `BlackBerry World` application directly:

```
function openAppStore() {

    var platform = $cordovaDevice.getPlatform().toLowerCase();
    var url;

    switch( platform ) {
        case "blackberry10":
            url = "appworld://content/xxxxxxxx";
            break;
        default:
            url = "anotherPlatformUrl"
    }

    if( platform === "blackberry10" ) {
        blackberry.invoke.invoke( {
            uri    : url
        }, onInvokeSuccess, onInvokeError );
    } else {
        window.open( url, "_system" );
    }

    function onInvokeSuccess() {
        console.log( "Invoke Success!" );
    }

    function onInvokeError( error ) {
        console.log( "!!! Invoke Error: ", error );
    }
}
```